# How to pass a PHP variable to Vue component instance in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I pass a value of a PHP variable to a Vue component in Laravel blade files?

In my example, I have an inline template client-details, I get this view from `Laravel` so now I want to pass the `id` which comes with the url `/client/1` to my `Vue` instance.

My component, which is loaded by `Laravel`, looks like:

```
<client-details inline-template>
    <div id="client-details" class="">
          My HTML stuff
    </div>
</client-details>
```

and mounted by:

```
Vue.component('client-details', {
    data(){
        return {
            clientId: null
        }
    },
);
```

I already tried like

```
:clientId="{{ $client->id }"
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to use Vue's `props` to be able to pass attributes to Vue's components through markup. Take a look at the following example:

```
<client-details inline-template client-id="{{ $client->id }}">
    <div id="client-details" class="">
          My HTML stuff
    </div>
</client-details>
```

In your Vue component:

```
Vue.component('client-details', {
    props: [
        {
            name: 'clientId',
            default:0,
        }
    ]
});
```

Now in other parts of your Vue component, you can access this value as `this.clientId`.

**Issue Details**

Please note that in HTML we write attribute name in **kebab-case** but in Vue side we write it in **camelCase**. More info in [official docs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props).

Also, you are using Vue's `v-bind` shorthand in `:clientId="{{ $client->id }}"` which means that Vue will deal anything inside double quotes as a JavaScript expression, therefore you may get errors in that case as well. Instead, you should use this format `clientId="{{ $client->id }}` without a colon.

Comment: Any change on this? I am getting "[Vue warn]: props must be strings when using array syntax" error. Edited: Solved by replacing props: ["clientId"]

Comment: This is not valid code: `<client-details inline-template client-id="{{ $client->id }}">`, you can not pass a PHP variable just like that

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ can you please elaborate?

Comment: @BillalBegueradj the OP used a `laravel` tag, obviously `{{ $client->id }}` is a syntax used by laravel's [blade](https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blade/) template engine and the assumption made here it entirely correct.

Comment: Why this `client-id="{{ $client->id }}"` and not `clientId="{{ $client->id }}"`. I don't see `client-id` anywhere. Just `clientId`

Comment: @IbrahimMohamed indeed this code is wrong

Comment: @IbrahimMohamed @sba that is Vue feature just to help with HTML and JS conventions, the camelCase `clientId` props you accept on Vue side, can be passed value using kebab-case `client-id` from HTML side. Read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Answer (score 14):

I just did this and it's working great for me. Using Laravel 5.4 and Vue 2.x.

In my component, declare a property (props) for the object:

`props: ['currentUser'],`

On my blade page where the component is instantiated:

`<my-component v-bind:current-user='{!! Auth::user()->toJson() !!}'></my-component>`

Note that in the component, I am using camelCase for `currentUser`, but because html is case-insensitive, you have to use kebab-case (thus, the 'current-user').

Also note, if you use blade syntax `{{  }}` then the data between is run through php `htmlspecialchars`. if you want unencoded data (which in this case you would), then use `{!! !!}`

Comment: also worth pointing out: **use single quotes** to encapsulate the object when passing it to the Vue component since `toJson()` uses double quotes in JSON entities.

Comment: I can confirm this also works for Laravel 8 with Vue 3.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who comes across this thread and is still getting errors, the answer is correctly given above by Mustafa Ehsan, but not explained. Trial and error helped me see it.

My component in newuser.blade.php

```
<access-request
       firstname="{{ $newuser->firstname }}"
       lastname="{{ $newuser->lastname }}"
       accessid="{{ $newuser->id }}"
>
</access-request>
```

Its very important to note the binding method used. On the component above, I wrote only the name of the data binding (like React props), then registered it on the component props (see below). This is how Mustafa wrote his binding in his answer, and works fine. The other, more Vue way to pass the props is with the v-bind: or :, but you have to make sure to use both double-quotes and single-quotes:

```
:firstname="'{{ $newuser->firstname }}'"
```

Without both quotes, you get Vue warnings.

AccessRequest.vue:

```
<template>
   <div class="component">
        <h3 class="">{{ firstname }} {{ lastname }}</h3>
        <p>Access ID: {{ accessid }}</p>
        <label for="administrator">Grant Administrator Priviledges:</label>
        <input name="administrator" type="checkbox" value="True" class="mb-5"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <hr>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AccessRequest",
    props: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'accessid'],
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to pass some server data to my Vue component, I ended up creating a `$server_data` variable in the controller and passing it in a json script tag.

In the controller:

```php
$server_data = json_encode([
    "some-data" => SomeObject::all()
]);

return View::make('myview', compact('server_data'));
```

In the template:

```php
<script type="application/json" name="server-data">
    {{ $server_data }}
</script>
<!-- Inserts server data into window.server_data -->
<script>
    var json = document.getElementsByName("server-data")[0].innerHTML;
    var server_data = JSON.parse(json);
</script>
```

In the vue initialisation, I put a computed property:

```js
computed: {
    'server_data': function(){
        return window.server_data;
    }
}
```

Then, the data is accessible in the component template with `server_data.some_object`.

This allows to pass a lot of structured data without needing many html attributes. Another benefit is that the data is escaped by the the json encoding. This avoids potential bugs with variables that contain double quotes ("), which would mess up the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Normally to pass php variable to vue I'd do

```
<component-name :prop-name='@json($variable)'></component-name>
```