# How to retrieve User name in Vue component with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a vue component that will send a message and I want to send the logged in user name. I'm using laravel 5.5

```
methods:{
        sendMessage(){
            this.$emit('messagesent', {
                message:this.messageText,
                user: {
                    name : {{Auth()::user()->name}} //Here is where it should be
                }
            });
            this.messageText = '';
        }
    }
```

I already tried using

```
{{Auth()::user()->name}}
Auth()::user()->name
```

Both give errors. How can I retrieve the name?

Comment: Pass the username through as a prop and use it like you're using `this.messageText`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass php variable to vue component instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520258/pass-php-variable-to-vue-component-instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depend on your approach, this can be achieve in different ways 
1. Pass in the username from the view
    `<send-message user={{ $user->username }} ></send-message>`
  then inside your vuejs component

```
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    data(){
        return {
           user: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage(){
            var user = JSON.parse(this.user)
            //do you thing here
        }
    },
}
```

2. Bind the user information to window object on your page header

```
<script>
    window.user = {!! json_encode([
        'user' => $user->username,
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

Comment: first way worked for me, sorry if it was an obvious question. new to Vue.

Comment: not related but by any chance you have experience with pusher with laravel and vue? So there is no need for a new question

Comment: What do you want to achieve? @CarlosF

Comment: trying to create several "chat rooms", individual chats, group chats and similar stuff. I have problem in how to create the chat rooms and sending the messages to the corresponding room.