# How do I pass data from PHP Laravel to Vue.js and re-render a Vue.js component when the data changes?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm still a bit new to Vue.js, so I may be fundamentally misunderstanding something about the reactivity of it, but basically, I want to pass some data from PHP Laravel to a Vue.js component ***and*** have the Vue.js component automatically update when that data changes.

I've seen several similar posts on SO suggest that I use `props` to pass the data from a Laravel Blade template to a Vue.js component. Here's an example:
[How to pass a PHP variable to Vue component instance in Laravel blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520258/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-vue-component-instance-in-laravel-blade)

I have this working perfectly fine, but now I'm stuck with how to get the component to update when the data dynamically changes after page-load.

Specifically, I have a report table on a particular web page, and when the user clicks certain buttons, etc., I use Ajax to call a Laravel controller action that re-runs a query in my Laravel model to get the new data for the report.

I have the data in a PHP array / JSON, and that data is being properly returned to the client-side and I have access to it in the JS, but now, what do I need to do to force the report component in Vue.js to essentially re-render based on the data I just received? Is there a way to "update props" so that Vue.js detects the change and automatically re-renders the whole report component for me?

This is where I'm stuck, and after quite a bit of research, I can't find how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Ajax **outside** of the Vue component? or within it as a method?

I have an example of how I dynamically update the Vue data from **within** the component itself. I'm not sure how to have external JS update the Vue component directly but I feel this is a good option to look at. I'm using [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) instead of Ajax but the principle is the same (Axios is included by default in most Laravel installs past 5.5).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="reports">
            <!-- Display data -->
            {{ reports }}
        </div>
        <button @click="refreshReports">Refresh</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                endpoint: '/api/MY_ROUTE/'
            };
        },

        props: {
            reports: Object
        },

        methods: {
            // Make Axios call to API endpoint
            refreshReports() {
                // GET version
                axios.get(this.endpoint)
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        this.reports = data.data;
                    });

                // POST version
                axios.post(this.endpoint, {
                    KEY: 'VALUE',
                }).then(({data}) => {
                    this.reports = data.data;
                });

                /*
                    `data.data` assumes the returned response is a JSON Resource

                    if it's not returning the correct data, put a `console.log(data)` and see how it's getting returned!
                 */
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Where in your `routes/api.php` file you have a route like this:

```php
// GET version
Route::get('MY_ROUTE', 'ReportController@getReports');

// POST version
Route::post('MY_ROUTE', 'ReportController@getReports');
```

And your Controller would have some method like this:

```php
// app/Http/Controllers/ReportController
public function getReports(Request $request) {
    return Reports::all();
}
```

Does that make sense?

---

Update:

> I'm not sure how to have external JS update the Vue component directly

I know you can import external JS scripts and use their functions in methods but I've never done it that way before.

Something like:

```
<script>
import { myFunction } from '../external.js'

export default {
    methods: {
        refreshReports() {
            // I have no idea if this is the correct way to do it, just a guess!
            this.reports = myFunction();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thank you very much. My main hangup was that I didn't know you could a) so easily access props via `this`, and b) I didn't think to assign the prop to a data property to get all the connectivity I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: To add to it a bit, basically, I had a prop called `report`. I then created a data property called `reportRows`, which I set to `this.report.rows` by default (from props). Then, in the method, if I set `this.reportRows` to whatever data came back, everything instantly updated. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, my pleasure! I added a little update at the end from someone else's answer in a different question but I haven't used that way before/nor do I know if that is the correct syntax. I always felt it was better to have my Ajax/axios call within the Vue component for readability and ease of use because Vue will detect if my data object has changed and then automatically re-draw the component with the new data.