# Trying to get a single data and display in a vue component, but nothing is displaying

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 5.8 + Vue.js in my project.
Trying to get a single data from a controller but nothing is displaying. 
I added the `12345` in the component to check if the component is working, `12345` is showing well.

**controller**

```php
  public function getSingleData($idx)
    {
      $paymentData = PaymentData::where('idx', $idx)->first();

      return view('paydetail')->with('paymentData', $paymentData);
    }
```

**router**

```php
Route::view('/paylist', 'paylist')->name('paylist.view');
Route::get('/paylist/data', 'PaymentController@getPaymentData')->name('paylist');
Route::get('/paydetail/{idx}', 'PaymentController@getSingleData')->name('paydetail');
```

**blade**

```php
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<div class="container">

    <paydetail :idx="{{ $paymentData->idx }}"></paydetail>
```

**app.js**

```php
Vue.component('paydetail', require('./components/Paydetail.vue').default);
```

**Paydetail.vue**

```js
<template>

<div>
  <h2>12345</h2>
  <div v-for="val in paymentData">
   <h2>{{ val.app_name }} </h2>
  </div>
</div>

</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  props: [ 'idx' ],
  data() {
      return {
          paymentData: [{}],
      }
  },
  created() {
    this.paymentData = this.getPayDetailData();
    console.log(this.idx);
    console.log("here");
  },
  methods: {
    getPayDetailData() {
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/paydetail/'+ this.idx
      }).then(
          response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error)
          }
      )
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The result of `console.log(response)` is weird. It shows the whole html document which I don't understand at all. 
It shows like this.

```php
{data: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta ch…>↵<!-- For Datatable -->↵↵↵    </body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

What did I wrong here?

Comment: Try returning the payment detail as json response instead a view

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Could you guide more specific?

Comment: yes, sure. In your function you are returning a view `return view('paydetail')->with('paymentData', $paymentData);` thats why you get "the whole html document"  result in your axios call.  Replace the return by `return response()->json(['data' => $paymentData]);` to return a json response. Then look in the console.log if it's the data you want

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Thank you for the explanation. But then, how can I display the ``paydetail.blade.php`` with the data?

Comment: in which blade is your component from where do you do axios call? I assumed that you had already loaded the blade view and with axios you just want to get the data to fill it

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ My vue component is in ``paydetail.blade.php`` and in the component, I want to get the data to fill. (Originally, it had written just laravel blade, but I'm trying to use vue.js in my project. That's why I'm so lost here.)

Comment: then you doesn't need the axios call, you can pass the whole object to the component as prop `<paydetail :paymentData="{{ $paymentData }}"></paydetail>` an in your component youa can receive it `props: [ 'paymentData' ],` and render `<h2>{{ paymentData.some_property }} </h2>`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Okay, I see. But I tried as you wrote but it occurs error like this. ``[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'app_name' of undefined"``

Comment: are you using Vue DevTools? if so, look if the `paymentData` prop is taken the value, o try to render the whole object `<code>{{ paymentData  }}</code>`. Also check if the php variable `$paymentData` is not empty. Note generally you shouldn't use `v-for` for a single object

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Thank you for your kindness. My Vue dev tools shows that ``props`` payment data is undefined but ``attrs`` shows the data correctly. and I checked the ``$paymentData``is not empty. Also, I dropped the v-for now.

Comment: but you have the prop and attr with same name `paymentData`? please, drop for now the attr, leave just this `<template><div>
<h2>12345</h2>
<h2>{{ paymentData }}
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: [ 'paymentData' ],
}
</script>`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I don't have anything for attr. I don't even know what it means. And I edited my code as you wrote but the result is the same. OTZ

Comment: try this in blade: `<paydetail :payment-data="{{ $paymentData }}"></paydetail>`. and in your component `<template><div> <h2>12345</h2> {{ paymentData }} </div> </template> <script> export default { props: [ { name: 'paymentData',  default:{}, } ], } </script>`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Now the error message is like this. ``[Vue warn]: props must be strings when using array syntax.`` and ``[Vue warn]: Property or method "paymentData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.``

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520258/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-vue-component-instance-in-laravel-blade

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Okay, I figured out. Thank you for your help. :)