# javascript syntax error while get data (object) from laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

get javascript syntax error in .blade.php for get $data->modal

my controller function :

```html
    public function buku_all($page, $modal)
    {$data = (object) [
            'sidebar' => "pelayanan",
            'breadcrumbsub' => 'Data Buku',
            'modal' => $modal
            'page' => $page
            ];
    return view('admin.buku')->with('data', $data);
    }
```

my js in admin/buku.blade.php

```html
if ($data->modal == 'book') {
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('#modal_edit_1').modal('show');
        });
    }
```

Comment: `my js in` for a start `$data->modal` is NOT valid JS

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot mix PHP and JS syntax.

```
@isset ($data)
   <script>
       let data = {{ json_encode($data) }};
       ...
   </script>
@endisset
```

Usually it's more alike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520258/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-vue-component-instance-in-laravel-blade).

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
@isset ($data)
   <script>
       var data = "{{ json_encode($data) }}";
       console.log(data);
       ...
   </script>
@endisset
```